# Is Ignoring SslPolicyErrors while doing SSL Pinning Secure?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, certificate

I am implementing SSL pinning as a security requirement for a project and the HTTPS endpoint is giving me SslPolicyErrors. The following errors occur,

```
RemoteCertificateChainErrors
    RevocationStatusUnknown
    UntrustedRoot
```

If I ignore these issues and just check that the public key `certificate.GetPublicKeyString ()` matches, will that be secure, or will hackers be able to spoof our certificate because we are not checking the chain?

Here's the code that checks for SslPolicyErrors that I am considering removing.

```
if (sslPolicyErrors != SslPolicyErrors.None) {
    Debug.Log(sslPolicyErrors);

    for(int i=0; i<chain.ChainStatus.Length;i++){
        Debug.Log("-");
        Debug.Log(chain.ChainStatus[i].Status);
        Debug.Log(chain.ChainStatus[i].StatusInformation);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you bought a TSL certificate then you must check root and revocation status. Those information must be validated to check if you are communicating with the correct endpoint.

If you use a self signed certificate then checking the finger print and the validity date should be faire game. But having the the fingerprint stored in the app makes it also easy to edit for a Man-in-the-Middle attack.

Maybe you ask about this and your protocol over at https://security.stackexchange.com/